# VB.net when I use a class I get 'System.NullReferenceException' when I use a module everything works, hopefully someone can explain why

Tags: vb.net

Description: I am using a Windows CE HMI, writing the code in vb.net. I am communicating with 4 flowmeters via Modbus RTU (RS485). I am using a dll for the Modbus communication. Now when I start a new thread in my program to run a part of a Module everything works OK and I am communicating with the 4 meters. So far so good. But now I want to make my code a bit more efficient and instead of throwing all code for four meters in a Module, I want to create 4 Classes.

I got this code in my main form (button) to create the object.

```
Dim Meter1 As New cModbusDriver(1) '(1) is the Modbus Meter ID
Dim Meter1_Thread As New Thread(AddressOf Meter1.ModbusDriver)

Meter1_Thread.IsBackground = True
Meter1_Thread.Start()
```

Below is a part of my Class:

```
Public Class cModbusDriver

    Private master As ModbusSerialMaster

    Public Sub ModbusDriver()

        While blnStopModbusThread = False

            Select Case intState
                Case 1
                    Try
                        Dim holding_register() As UShort = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, 0, 8)

                        Flow = HextoFloat.ConvertHexToSingle((Hex(holding_register(1)) &      Hex(holding_register(0))))
```

The error System.NullReferenceException comes from the line `Dim holding_register() As UShort = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(2, 0, 8)`.  I can see that when I put a break point there.

But why is this not working as when I use a Module it works fine?

Hopefully someone has an idea.

thanks,
Maurits

Answer (score 5):

Classes are **reference types**. When you declare a variable for a class, all you have is a place to keep a *reference*; you don't have an actual object yet, and you must assign a reference to an **instance** of your variable before you can use it:

```
Private master As New ModbusSerialMaster() 'Adding the New operator creates an instance
```

or:

```
Private master As ModbusSerialMaster
master = New ModbusSerialMaster()
```

or:

```
Private master As ModbusSerialMaster = SomeMethodThatReturnsYourClass()
```

Modules are **value types**. Value type variables store the object directly. They hold an object's actual *value*, rather than just a potential *reference* to an object somewhere in memory. This means they are never `null`. (This is why the `Module` version of the code in your question works.) However, you can also create and assign new instances if you need to.

*Value types have some drawbacks in the .Net world by default, such that you should generally prefer to use a Class most of the time.*

---

Understanding the differences between an object type, an object instance, a reference, and a variable is a **core skill** in programming. *Until you master this you will struggle to write effective code.*

Here is what an object **type** looks like in code:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Bar As String
End Class
```

Here we declare a **variable** for that type:

```
Dim baz As Foo
```

No object instances or references exist yet in that code — we haven't actually allocated any memory to hold a `Foo` object — so let's create an **instance** of the type:

```
Dim baz As New Foo()
```

or:

```
Dim baz As Foo = New Foo()
```

Both examples not only create the instance, but also assign a **reference** to the `baz` variable.

Here is an example using an object instance with no variable reference:

```
(New System.Net.WebClient()).DownloadString("http://www.example.com")
```

---

Let's backup and bit and talk some more about reference types vs value types. Specifically, what happens when you pass them as arguments to a method. Take this method:

```
Public Sub Foo(Bar As SomeValueType)
```

When you pass an argument for the `Bar` parameter to this method, you copy the entire object. For small objects this is fine, but for larger objects this is a problem. Additionally, changes to the `Bar` variable in the method won't be visible to the original variable when the method is over.

We can fix this somewhat by changing to pass `ByRef`:

```
Public Sub Foo(ByRef Bar As SomeValueType)
```

Now when we call `Foo` we pass a reference to the original variable. We don't have to copy the entire object, and changes to `Bar` in the method are made to the original object, so they will be available when the method ends and returns to the caller. However, there are also some drawbacks to this approach, as well.

Now let's look at a reference type:

```
Public Sub Foo(Bar As SomeReferenceType)
```

This method is again using the default `ByVal` passing mechanism. However, *the object is not copied!* **Only the reference is copied when passing a reference type `ByVal`.** However, because this reference copy still points to the same object in memory, you see all the state data from your object; changes to properties of the object will be seen in the original when the method ends. *This is the way you should write your methods most of the time.*

Finally, we can also pass a reference type `ByRef`:

```
Public Sub Foo(Bar As SomeReferenceType)
```

In this case, the reference itself is passed `ByRef`. For all intents and purposes you are now effectively using the *same variable*. That is, you can even assign a brand new object to the reference, and the original variable will now also refer to that object. This is useful, but not as much as you might think, and most of the time the default `ByVal` passing convection is what you want.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're getting at with the paragraph that starts with, "Modules are value types."  Modules most certainly are not value types, they're roughly a singleton class, I've never seen a module referenced in code as an entire entity, and they can contain null reference types as data.  The difference is IMO very likely due to having a module-level variable that got initialized somehow and missing that initialization when it was converted to classes.

Comment: @Craig Did you mean to say *static* class?

Comment: @SteveCinq `static class` would certainly be the description in C# (though as I recall .Net does have an actual `module` in it, which may or may not be what a C# `static class` compiles to).

Comment: @Craig VB.NET *Module* = C#.NET *Static Class* as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @SteveCinq It's a highly technical distinction in any event, as in any practical sense, I would use a C# `static class` the same way I would use a VB `Module`.

Comment: Sigh... I do know better. Really. For some reason I was reading "Module" but my brain was processing "Struct" :(

Answer (score 0):

Modules function as containers for global variables and global functions.  The problem with global data is that it's easy to have hidden dependencies between routines that aren't obvious from a quick inspection.  If your module implementation has `Private master As ModbusSerialMaster` and a routine assigns to `master`, *then all subsequent routines will also see the same value on `master`*.  When you convert to using classes, each class instance has its own copy of `master`, and the changes from the aforementioned routine never propagate to the class instances.

You can get a similar global effect with a class by making a member `Shared`, but I would recommend against doing it this way.

The best way to address this is through **dependency injection**.  You should set up your code so that when you create an instance of `cModBusDriver`, you provide it with the `ModBusSerialMaster` that you want it to use.  The most straightforward way of doing this will usually be as a constructor argument (an argument to `Sub New`).